# How to use an Intrinsic attributes as types in TypeScript react-native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

How do you make use of Intrinsic attributes as types in typeScript.

I have a simple tab navigation that looks like:

```
  const getOptions = (iconName: string) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({ color }: { color: string }) => (
      <MaterialIcons name={iconName} size={24} color={color} />
    ),
  });


<Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={() => getOptions("home")}
      />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

`MaterialIcons` from `@expo/vector-icons` has a property `name` which is of type `GLYPHS`.

When I use `iconName: string` I get the following error:

> The expected type comes from property 'name' which is declared here on
> type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the property `name` of the `MaterialIcons` component expects a [`String literal type`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), whilst you're trying to assign a `string` type to it.

Because there is not an exported `String literal type` from the [`@types/react-native-vector-icons`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-native-vector-icons) or in the [`@expo/vector-icons`](https://docs.expo.io/guides/icons/#expovector-icons) package, you'll have to define your own type for it.

A possible solution would be to declare the type of the `iconName` attribute to be of type `'home'` instead of `string`:

```
const getOptions = (iconName: 'home') => ({
  tabBarIcon: ({ color }: { color: string }) => (
    <MaterialIcons name={iconName} size={24} color={color} />
  ),
});


<Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen
      name="HomeScreen"
      component={HomeScreen}
      options={() => getOptions("home")}
    />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

You would have to extend this type if you would need more icon names in it, of course. For example if you want to add an article screen to your `Tab.Navigator` in the future:

```
// iconName is of 'home' | 'article' string literal type now
const getOptions = (iconName: 'home' | 'article') => ({
  tabBarIcon: ({ color }: { color: string }) => (
    <MaterialIcons name={iconName} size={24} color={color} />
  ),
});

<Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} options={() => getOptions('home')} />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="ArticleScreen"
    component={ArticleScreen}
    options={() => getOptions('article')}
  />
</Tab.Navigator>;
```